# Any idea how to disable auto play on embedded "Vine.co" videos?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autoplay

I'm working on a little side project.

I'm able to embed and display specified vine.co video's with

```
<iframe id='eFrame' src='http://vine.co/v/bJjdTLBnwx1/card' width='380' height='380' frameborder='0'></iframe>
```

I'm pulling in the links via Ajax to display them on the page, however now the problem is they are all autoplaying, which causes major browser lag.

Anyone know how I can append them to the body with **autoplay disabled**? This project is all client side, so I'll be limited to client-side languages. (ie Javascript/jQuery etc..)

Much appreciated, Cheers.

Comment: You can not touch the content in the iframe since it is a different domain.

Comment: True, might have to figure out another way of embedding the video's.

Comment: What about faking the iframe and only loading it (inclusive autoplay) when required?

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably late but you can pass some command via the postMessage javascript's function. It worked for me :

```
var iframe = document.getElementById(id);

iframe.contentWindow.postMessage('pause', '*');
```

Same construction for play, mute and unmute.

Comment: Interesting way, but not working for me. Can you explain a bit the second line?

Answer (score -2):

`<iframe id='eFrame' src='http://vine.co/v/bJjdTLBnwx1/embed/simple' width='320' height='320' frameborder='0'></iframe>`

Try this it will be of much help have better controls and only on pressing the play button it will run.

Try it.

Comment: This will in fact disable autoplay if the iframe is not in the viewport. As soon as it is visible, it will auto play. If you have in the viewport more than one vine embedded, they will all auto play at same time.

Comment: it might not work now, but, it was working. There must be some change from vine side.