# Disabling Embedded Vine Autoplay

Tags: vine

Note: Answers posted here: [Any idea how to disable auto play on embedded "Vine.co" videos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615370) are outdated

Given an embedded vine video iframe such as:

```html
<iframe src="https://vine.co/v/ibAU6OH2I0K/embed/simple" width="600" height="600" frameborder="0"></iframe><script src="https://platform.vine.co/static/scripts/embed.js"></script>
```

Is there any way to *disable* autoplaying the video?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any idea how to disable auto play on embedded "Vine.co" videos?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615370/any-idea-how-to-disable-auto-play-on-embedded-vine-co-videos)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there's an unpublished query parameter you can add to the src: `autoplay=(0|1)`